# How to use string concatenation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried replacing ':insertx:', ':inserty:', ':insertz:' from the storyText string with the variables itemX, itemY, itemZ but when I run the program, it does not replace.

Is there a way to rewrite the storytext string with concatnation (adding the itemXYZ variables) instead of using the .replace() method?

```js
//1. COMPLETE VARIABLE AND FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

var customName = document.getElementById('customname');
var randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
var story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array){
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

//2. TEXT STRINGS
let storyText = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so :insertx: went for a walk. When they got to :inserty:, they stared in horror for a few moments, then :insertz:. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — :insertx: weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.';
let insertX = ['Willy the Goblin', 'Big Daddy', 'Father Christmas'];
let insertY = ['the soup kitchen','Disneyland', 'the White House'];
let insertZ = ['spontaneously combusted','melted into a puddle on the sidewalk','turned into a slug and crawled away'];

//3. EVENT LISTENER AND PARTIAL FUNCTION DEFINITION

randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {

  let newStory = storyText;
  let itemX = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let itemY = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let itemZ = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  //replaces inserts in stortText w/ randomized strings from itemX,Y,Z
  newStory = newStory.replace(':insertx:', itemX);
  newStory = newStory.replace(':inserty:', itemY);
  newStory = newStory.replace(':insertz:', itemZ);
  newStory = newStory.replace(':insertx:', itemX);

  //replaces 'Bob' w/ custom name if given
  if(customName.value !== '') {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Bob', name);
  }

  //converts fahrenheit to centigrade & pounds to stone
  if(document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let temperature =  Math.round((94 - 32) * 5/9) + ' centigrade';
    let weight = Math.round(300 * 0.071429) +  ' stone';
    newStory = newStory.replace('94 fahrenheit', temperature);
    newStory = newStory.replace('300 pounds', weight);
  }

  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
p {
  background: #FFC125;
  color: #5E2612;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="generatorStyles.css">

    <title>Silly story generator</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="customname">Enter custom name:</label>
      <input id="customname" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="us">US</label><input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
      <label for="uk">UK</label><input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="randomize">Generate random story</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Thanks a lot to Willy Aguirre for his help with the code for this assessment -->
    <p class="story"></p>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include ***all*** the relevant code necessary to reproduce your issue. This includes HTML and CSS. And, place your code into a "code snippet" so that we can run it right here.

Comment: Have you clicked your button a few times? Your code works.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the code works. I am trying to ask if there is a way to do this: let storyText = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so insertX ...;

Comment: ???? Yes, the way to do it is the way you've done it. Your code does what you are saying it doesn't do.

Comment: Hi @TylerMorales, try looking into template literals.

Comment: My  reason in asking this question is to clean up some of the JS. Instead of writing newStory = newStory.replace(':insertx:', itemX); for each variable, I was wondering if I could go into the storyText string and use the variable name while concatenating. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using template literals. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
//1. COMPLETE VARIABLE AND FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

var customName = document.getElementById('customname');
var randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
var story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array){
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

//2. TEXT STRINGS
let insertX = ['Willy the Goblin', 'Big Daddy', 'Father Christmas'];
let insertY = ['the soup kitchen','Disneyland', 'the White House'];
let insertZ = ['spontaneously combusted','melted into a puddle on the sidewalk','turned into a slug and crawled away'];

//3. EVENT LISTENER AND PARTIAL FUNCTION DEFINITION

randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {

  
  let itemX = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let itemY = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let itemZ = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  //replaces inserts in stortText w/ randomized strings from itemX,Y,Z
  let newStory = `It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so ${itemX} went for a walk. When they got to ${itemY}, they stared in horror for a few moments, then ${itemZ}. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — ${itemX} weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.`;

  //replaces 'Bob' w/ custom name if given
  if(customName.value !== '') {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Bob', name);
  }

  //converts fahrenheit to centigrade & pounds to stone
  if(document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let temperature =  Math.round((94 - 32) * 5/9) + ' centigrade';
    let weight = Math.round(300 * 0.071429) +  ' stone';
    newStory = newStory.replace('94 fahrenheit', temperature);
    newStory = newStory.replace('300 pounds', weight);
  }

  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
p {
  background: #FFC125;
  color: #5E2612;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="generatorStyles.css">

    <title>Silly story generator</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="customname">Enter custom name:</label>
      <input id="customname" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="us">US</label><input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
      <label for="uk">UK</label><input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="randomize">Generate random story</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Thanks a lot to Willy Aguirre for his help with the code for this assessment -->
    <p class="story"></p>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the random strings directly into the story, which should be moved into the `result` function.

```js
//1. COMPLETE VARIABLE AND FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

var customName = document.getElementById('customname');
var randomize = document.querySelector('.randomize');
var story = document.querySelector('.story');

function randomValueFromArray(array){
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

//2. TEXT STRINGS
let insertX = ['Willy the Goblin', 'Big Daddy', 'Father Christmas'];
let insertY = ['the soup kitchen','Disneyland', 'the White House'];
let insertZ = ['spontaneously combusted','melted into a puddle on the sidewalk','turned into a slug and crawled away'];

//3. EVENT LISTENER AND PARTIAL FUNCTION DEFINITION

randomize.addEventListener('click', result);

function result() {

  let itemX = randomValueFromArray(insertX);
  let itemY = randomValueFromArray(insertY);
  let itemZ = randomValueFromArray(insertZ);

  let newStory = 'It was 94 fahrenheit outside, so ' + itemX + ' went for a walk. When they got to ' + itemY + '", they stared in horror for a few moments, then ' + itemZ + '. Bob saw the whole thing, but was not surprised — ' + itemX + ' weighs 300 pounds, and it was a hot day.';

  //replaces 'Bob' w/ custom name if given
  if(customName.value !== '') {
    let name = customName.value;
    newStory = newStory.replace('Bob', name);
  }

  //converts fahrenheit to centigrade & pounds to stone
  if(document.getElementById("uk").checked) {
    let temperature =  Math.round((94 - 32) * 5/9) + ' centigrade';
    let weight = Math.round(300 * 0.071429) +  ' stone';
    newStory = newStory.replace('94 fahrenheit', temperature);
    newStory = newStory.replace('300 pounds', weight);
  }

  story.textContent = newStory;
  story.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 350px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
div {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
p {
  background: #FFC125;
  color: #5E2612;
  padding: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
   <div>
      <label for="customname">Enter custom name:</label>
      <input id="customname" type="text" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="us">US</label><input id="us" type="radio" name="ukus" value="us" checked>
      <label for="uk">UK</label><input id="uk" type="radio" name="ukus" value="uk">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="randomize">Generate random story</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Thanks a lot to Willy Aguirre for his help with the code for this assessment -->
    <p class="story"></p>
```

Comment: It works the way I presented it, but was wondering if there is a way to replace the ':insertx:' within the storyText string itself for the variable itemX  in the result function instead of using the .replace method?